# Remove vertical space between author affiliation and abstract in \documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

Tags: spacing, elsarticle

How to remove the verticle space between Author affiliation and Abstract in elsarticle class. Thank you

```
    \documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{times}

% use to remove rules (top and bottom lines) of Abstract"
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remove first horizontal rule (above abstract)
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remoce second horizonral rule (below keywords)

\begin{filecontents*}{mybibfile.bib}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}

%\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% use to remove footer " preprint submitted to elsevier"
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother


\author{hariharan\corref{cor1}*}
\address{\normalfont{ Fukuoka, Japan\\ 
Email : hari.ac.jp }}

\title{My title My title My title My title My title My title My title  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text  Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text  Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text Some Some text text  
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
Remove space between author affilioation and abstract in elsarticle class. Remove space between author affilioation and abstract in elsarticle class. Remove space between author affilioation and abstract in elsarticle class. Remove space between author affilioation and abstract in elsarticle class. Remove space between author affilioation and abstract in elsarticle class. Remove space between author affilioation and abstract in elsarticle class. Remove space between author affilioation and abstract in elsarticle class.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `frontmatter` environment in [`elsarticle`](//ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) issues `\maketitle` at `\end{frontmatter}`:

```
\newenvironment{frontmatter}
  {}          % \begin{frontmatter}
  {\maketitle}% \end{frontmatter}
```

The setup for `\maketitle` depends on a number of things passed as document class options. However, the information detailing the construction of the title is contained within `\MaketitleBox`:

```
\long\def\MaketitleBox{%
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \begin{center}%
   \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \Large\@title\par\vskip18pt
    \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
    \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
    \hrule\vskip12pt
    \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    \hrule\vskip12pt
    \end{center}%
  }
```

Note how you've already removed the two `\hrule` macros with your [`xpatch`](//ctan.org/pkg/xpatch):

```
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remove first horizontal rule (above abstract)
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remoce second horizonral rule (below keywords)
```

However, you've left the remaining `\vskip12pt` after each - these are the vertical spaces between the title/author-and-abstract and abstract-and-text-body. We can change your patch to

```
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule\vskip12pt}{\vspace{-2\baselineskip}}{}{}% remove first horizontal rule (above abstract) + space
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remoce second horizonral rule (below keywords)
```

which replaces the rule and vertical skip with a negative skip.

Original output:

[image]

Updated output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{times,lipsum}

% use to remove rules (top and bottom lines) of Abstract"
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule\vskip12pt}{\vspace{-2\baselineskip}}{}{}% remove first horizontal rule (above abstract) + space
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remoce second horizonral rule (below keywords)

\usepackage{hyperref}

\author{An author\corref{cor1}*}
\address{An address \\ 
  Email : who@cares.com
}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
  \begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

There are additional skips when using `keywords`, but that's not covered in this question. However, you can remove/change these as well.

Comment: Consider `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` or `\usepackage{mathptmx}` instead of `\usepackge{times}`.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using `\vspace{-length}` command after address. The command adds negative vertical space (i.e. take space away).

```
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My title My title My title My title My title My title My title  }

\author{hariharan\corref{cor1}*}

\address{\normalfont{ Fukuoka, Japan **\vspace{-0.5cm}**\\ 
}}


\begin{abstract}
Some text  
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}
```