# Elsarticle cross-reference of Table and Figure in blue color

Tags: cross-referencing, elsarticle

```
\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}


\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}


\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks   = true,
        citecolor    = blue
    }



\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

%\begin{table}[H]
\begin{table*}
\caption{Comparison} \label{accuracy_static_defl}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline 
\multirow{3}{*}{Smith($\mu$)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Numerical solution}\\ \cline{2-3}&Deflection($\mu$)&error\\ \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5}
&App 1 &App2\\
\hline
 100.34500&100.345098&100.0286& \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{table*}

Table.\ref{accuracy_static_defl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I change the color of the word "Table" from black to blue when I cross-refer this table. Same for the figures cross-reference. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please put your question in the question - comments are subject to deletion. Have you looked at `hyperref`'s manual? You just pick the relevant option - just as you have for citations. What's the problem exactly? You never really say.

Comment: Thank for the quick response. When I cross-refer the Tables and the Figures, I would like to get Table.1 (In blue color) and Fig.1 (In blue color). Now I am getting only the number in blue but not the Table.1 and Fig.1. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @koleygr, I did not get any answers before for my questions on cross-reference and citation. I would appreciate anyone answered. I will definitely accept answers. Thank you. How do I get colored cross-reference of Tables and Figures?

Comment: @Prakash Did you checked my answer? I didn't checked your questions before and I am going to delete my above comment. The only open question I see with non-accepted answer by you is this : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383655/remove-vertical-space-between-author-affiliation-and-abstract-in-documentclass... The others are closed or unanswered... But it is not big deal... Deleting my previous comment...(Sorry!... Just show too many white questions in your profile)

Comment: @koleygr, Thank you so much, I was looking for this answer.

Comment: @Prakash, If you find any problem (like if you don't want cleveref or whatever) you can use the same idea to redefine just the simple `\ref` command. But then it could be better to use a standar way for the labels, like fig:something for figures and tab:something for tables... If you want I can add this way to my answer. (You are welcome)

Comment: @koleygr, please add to your answer.  I am very happy with your kind support. Sincerely thank you. Also is it possible to get a capital letter (table 1 to Table 1)? Thank you very much

Comment: @Prakash Sorry but I was working on something... Added the second answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit without cleveref (redefining `\ref` but using `xstring`):**

```
\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}


\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks   = true,
        citecolor    = blue,
        linkcolor=blue  %%%ADDED for the links (needed in e.g. article)
    }



%%%ADDED FOR THE ANSWER
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{fig:}%
{{\color{blue}Figure~\oldref{#1}}}%
{\IfBeginWith{#1}{tab:}{{\color{blue}Table~\oldref{#1}}}{Unsupported ref start}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Comparison} \label{tab:accuracy_static_defl}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline 
\multirow{3}{*}{Smith($\mu$)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Numerical solution}\\ \cline{2-3}&Deflection($\mu$)&error\\ \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5}
&App 1 &App2\\
\hline
 100.34500&100.345098&100.0286& \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}


\begin{figure}
\caption{Comparison} \label{fig:accuracy_static_defl}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\centering

\end{figure}

In the \ref{fig:accuracy_static_defl} or the \ref{tab:accuracy_static_defl}...
```

Output:

[image]

**Old Answer with cleveref:**

Here is an answer for you to check because I have not the cls file:

```
\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}


\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks   = true,
        citecolor    = blue,
        linkcolor=blue  %%%ADDED for the links (needed in e.g. article)
    }

%%%ADDED FOR THE ANSWER
\usepackage{cleveref}
\let\oldcref\cref
\def\cref#1{\color{blue}\oldcref{#1}}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

%\begin{table}[H]
\begin{table*}
\caption{Comparison} \label{accuracy_static_defl}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline 
\multirow{3}{*}{Smith($\mu$)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Numerical solution}\\ \cline{2-3}&Deflection($\mu$)&error\\ \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5}
&App 1 &App2\\
\hline
 100.34500&100.345098&100.0286& \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{table*}

In the \cref{accuracy_static_defl}..

\end{document}
```

The idea is to use `cleveref` package that provides `\cref` command. And I redefined this command to print everything in blue. (The colorlinks)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already loading the `hyperref` package, all you need to do is (a) to load the `cleveref` package with the options `nameinlink` and `noabbrev` and (b) to use either `\cref` or `\Cref` (the latter if the first character of the label should be upper-cased) instead of `\ref`.

That way, not only will the "labels" ("Figure" and "Table") be rendered in blue, the labels will also be part of the hyperlink, i.e., of the string that readers can click on in order to jump to the respective target.

[image]

```
\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, allcolors = blue}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} % <-- new

\begin{document}
%% Create dummy table and figure environments:
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparison} \label{accuracy_static_defl}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Hello World} \label{hello}
\end{figure}

\Cref{accuracy_static_defl} shows that \dots\ 
As was shown in \cref{hello}, \dots
\end{document}
```